# Working with several installed pythons

Tags: 18.04, python, python3

I have Ubuntu 18.04, so it has python3.6 installed by default. I can call it using

```
python3
```

Ubuntu doesn't have any python2 installed now (by default also).

I want to use python3.7 for my projects. So I installed it and now can call it using

```
python3.7
```

My idea - I want to call just `python` and `pip` instead of `python3.7` and `pip3.7` but I don't want to crush some system configurations. I read a lot of different answers about `alias` and `update-alternatives`:
for example:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496461/how-to-make-python3-7-default

But all of them usually about python2 and python3 and still use `python3` at prompt!
So what solution I need to apply?

P.S.
Some additional info - I want to use some virtual environments then for it and I'm thinking about `pipenv` now - could be some diffuculties here if I use just `python` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the /usr/bin directory and look at the current symlinks for Python:

```
ls -l python*
```

You should see 2 symlinks: one referencing python3.6 and the other referencing python3.6-config. Delete those symlink files:

```
sudo rm python python-config
```

Now create new symlinks to the python version you want; python3.7 in this case:

```
sudo ln -s python3.7 python
sudo ln -s python3.7-config python-config
```

Check your work:

```
ls -l python*
```

If you see the new symlinks referencing python3.7, then do one final check to see if the default version is the one you want:

```
python -V
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ln -s python3.7 python`? This is just from memory of using symlinks.
Edit: Never mind, you've fixed it.

Comment: Since `/usr/bin` is owned by root user, `rm` and `ln` won't work unless used with `sudo`. Moreover, you can "forcefully" change symlinks without even deleting them using `f` option.

Comment: @Eric thank you for your response!
Using `ls -l python*` I can see: `python3 -> python3.6 python3m -> python3.6m` I have no config! Can I just create create symlink for `python` using your solution? Smth like python -> python3.7

Comment: @Kulfy can you clarify this moment for me, please? (previous comment)

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam try running pip3 install python-config

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Yes you can as long as there's no application which actually depends on Python 2. Python isn't backward compatible. python3-config isn't available by default and is optional (AFAIK).